# Formatted cell as a number at Excel - Kendo UI - Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need a codes that need to do formatted cell at excel. I have a grid and i can export this data as an excel document everything is fine but i wanted to set some column(Like salary, stock) as number cell in Excel

I don't know how it can be possible. If you know please let me know ;)

Comment: Are you asking how to format a cell in excel using Kendo UI?

Comment: yes. I can export data but every cell is an general cell. i would like to change some cell as number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use excelExport function and set format there. Important is that you need value which is written into xml. (I didn't figure out if there is another way)

[Kendo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/eJeyE) with number formated cells...

Also check [this site](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-78f2a361-936b-4c03-8772-09fab54be7f4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to see what is supported by excel.